# automatic creation of custom post type articles

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

I have an external database besides WordPress which has a table with genealogical data. In WordPress, I have created a Custom Post Type (CPT) and for these genealogical records. There is also a related custom field belonging to the CPT post.

Now I am looking for the code to auto-create these CPT posts and fill the custom field with an URL;  one per row in the external database. How can this be accomplished with `wp_insert_post`?

Comment: For sake of completion:  the number of rows in the external database is ~800 and might grow to 1000+.   The creation would be done 2-3x per year, and like to add the code into and deactived plugin for this housekeeping activity.

Comment: Read the function complete details [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)